# Usar variable de Javascript en Mustache

Tags: javascript, html

Buen día!
Soy completamente nuevo con html, css y moustache por lo que puede que sean preguntas obvias para muchos.

Estoy trabajando en una creación de factura tipo PDF dinámica con mustache y no se me ocurre cómo hacer interactuar mustache con js

Lo que trato de hacer es esto:

```
<script>
  var tipoDeFactura = {{{{wrapper.tipoFactura}}}};
  var isA = tipoDeFactura== 'A';
  var isB = tipoDeFactura == 'B';

</script>

{{#isA}}
    <p>wrapper.impuesto1 </p>
    <p>wrapper.impuesto2 </p>
    <p>wrapper.impuesto3 </p>
    <p>wrapper.impuesto4 </p>
{{/isA}}
{{^isA}}
    {{#isB}}
        <p> wrapper.impuestos</p>
    {{/isB}}
{{/isA}}
```

osea, que si la factura es tipo A muestre los campos del wrapper detallando los impuestos, si es b que muestre el total de impuestos sin detalle.

El problema es que js no reconoce el mustache ni viseversa (si le asigno var tipoDeFactura = {{{{wrapper.tipoFactura}}}} a una variable del html tipoDeFactura esta vacio porque no "ve" a {{wrapper.tipoFactura}} y  si pruebo {{isA}} me da que el campo es incorrecto).

¿Hay alguna forma de que se "vean"? ¿o de utilizar variables como "isA" sin modificar el wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

Tal como pone en la [documentación](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) de mustachejs tienes que tener una plantilla html que usa la sintaxis de mustachejs dentro del tag `<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache"></script>` y con el atributo `type="x-tmpl-mustache"` para que mustache pueda parsear la template a javascript.

La template no se renderiza por si sola, tienes que renderizarla desde js, es decir, coger la plantilla e insertarla como html válido.

No puedes tener código js en la template mustache todas las variables se pasan desde la función `Mustache.render`

```
<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  {{#isA}}
    <p>wrapper.impuesto1 </p>
    <p>wrapper.impuesto2 </p>
    <p>wrapper.impuesto3 </p>
    <p>wrapper.impuesto4 </p>
{{/isA}}
{{^isA}}
    {{#isB}}
        <p> wrapper.impuestos</p>
    {{/isB}}
{{/isA}}
</script>
```

En tu script js

```
function render() {
  const tipoDeFactura = 'A';
  const datosTemplate = {
    title: 'Factura',
    isA: tipoDeFactura === 'A',
    isB: tipoDeFactura === 'B'
  }
  const template = document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
  const rendered = Mustache.render(template, /* aqui van los datos que quieras pasar a la template*/ datosTemplate );
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = rendered;
}
```

Comment: Pero si estoy trabajando sobre un framework que lo unico que me brinda es el html? no tengo acceso al js que levanta el html/mustache, lo que unico que puedo probar es meter <scripts> ¿no es posible desde la misma plantilla levantar las variables del script y vicecersa (que el js interactue con las variables del wrapper del entorno)?

Comment: puedes meter tu js en un tag `<script></script>` y tener la funcion de `render` ahí. No habría ningun problema

Comment: Entiendo que generas las variables en render() y al usar Mustache.render el mustache debería reconocerlas como si fueran del wrapper verdad? Porque no me funcionó, no entiendo bien por qué pero no me reconoce las variables rendereadas en la funcion. Lo terminé resolviendo ocultándolo/mostrándolo con css, pero no me gusta demasiado

Comment: si puedes actualizar tu pregunta con lo que intentaste quiza te pueda ayudar